# Ограничить количество памяти, которое процесс может затребовать

Tags: c++, qt

Как на Qt ограничить приложению оперативную память? Чтобы, к примеру, выделить 100мб и ни капли больше. И пускай приложение работает в этих рамках. Есть ли встроенный менеджер памяти? Подскажите, в каких направлениях в Qt двигаться для реализации задачи контроля оперативной памяти?

Comment: Выделить где? В хипе, на стеке, в файле подкачки, в адресном пространстве? Что значит "пускай приложение работает в этих рамках" - как приложение об этом узнает? Что должно произойти если оно потребует памяти за пределами рамок? Очень странный вопрос.

Comment: Вы для работы или для отладки? Если для отладки, установить искусственные ограничения под Windows умеет стандартный AppVerifier. (Ну и наверняка под линуксом тоже что-то подобное есть.)

Comment: В Linux можете попробовать [ulimit](http://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html)

Comment: В хипе. Создать свою область памяти(свой файл подкачки) и в этих рамках работать. Вот цель. Что подскажете?

Answer (score 2):

Никаких встроенных менеджеров памяти или просто каких-то контроллеров за её использованием в Qt не имеется. Оно и не удивительно, поскольку обозначенный фреймворк для этого и не предназначен. Если требуется функционал по ограничению использования конкретным процессом оперативной памяти, то обращайтесь к соответствующим нативным средствам непосредственно той операционной системы, которую используете. Qt - фреймворк для разработки кроссплатформенных приложений общего назначения, наибольшую часть которого составляет функционал по реализации графического интерфейса пользователя.